# MVC EF - datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetimepicker

This is my class:

```
 public partial class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        this.PostImages = new HashSet<PostImage>();
        this.PostMappings = new HashSet<PostMapping>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleMenu { get; set; }
    public string Preview { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Display { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAdded { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateHide { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PozitionMenu { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PostImage> PostImages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostMapping> PostMappings { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update the column *DateHide*.

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateHide, new { @class = "jquery_datepicker", @Value = (!Model.DateHide.HasValue ? "" : Model.DateHide.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))})

     $('.jquery_datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

I added in web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" />
```

And I still get the error:

*The value '20/02/2014' is not valid for DateHide.*

Comment: `dd/mm/yy` isn't a US date format.

Comment: Ok. I removed globalization from web.config but I still get the same error.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Where did you get the error?

Comment: When I'm trying to update Post element.

Comment: You should try it like `mm/dd/yyyy`.  Also where is the error?  When you insert into the database?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$('.jquery_datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

by

```
$('.jquery_datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
```

This will pass the date in the format of "02/20/2014" to the model.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateHide, new { @class = "jquery_datepicker", @Value = (!Model.DateHide.HasValue ? "" : Model.DateHide.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))})
```

with

```
  <span class="jquery_datepicker">    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateHide, new { @class = "jquery_datepicker", @Value =Model.DateHide, displayMode })</span>
```

and

```
$('.jquery_datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

with

```
 $('.jquery_datepicker input').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

Now it works! But I don't know why. What is the difference between *EditorFor* and *TextboxFor*?